# upgraded mysql to 5.5 on windows / php doesn't connect to mysql API

Tags: php, mysql, iis

i was upgraded mysql to 5.5

but i don't know why php does not connect to mysql API

in info file written

Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev

my server is windows server / using IIS

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network.

You’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if your question is clearer, shows some of the research you’ve done, what you’ve tried, what errors you got, etc. Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: look here
http://monojo.com.jo/index1.php

why it still 5.0.11 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Installation**

First thing to do after you [download](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) and extract phpMyAdmin is place the extracted files in the appropriate directory inside your IIS web root so that IIS is able to access it. You may wish to create a separate website for your phpMyAdmin installation, or simply add it as a sub directory or virtual directory under an existing website. Either way you'll need to make sure that the user account used by IIS to access your files has at least NTFS read permissions to all of your files once they are in place.

In this guide we'll place the phpMyAdmin files in a directory called "pma" under the root directory of a website "example.com". Because phpMyAdmin enables you to directly manipulate, and even delete entire databases and users, it is highly recommended that you secure your phpMyAdmin installation using SSL. This can be done by purchasing a certificate from a 3rd party vendor which will cost money, or by [creating self signed certificate for IIS yourself](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/creating_self_signed_certificates_iis) at no cost. With all this in mind, then to access the phpMyAdmin installation used in this guide you would type the following into the address bar of your favourite web browser;

**PHP Settings**

phpMyAdmin uses several PHP extensions to perform its various functions. The extensions you'll need for phpMyAdmin are;

MySQL (to connect to the MySQL server on web hosting)
MCrypt (highly recommended for performance when using the cookie authentication method, and actually required for 64-bit environments)
MBString (used for multi-byte character support)
GD2 (image creation and manipulation library)
To enable these extensions open you `php.ini` file and navigate to the list of extensions and find these extension names;

```
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Simply **remove the semi-colon (`;`) from that start**, save the file and restart IIS to reload your PHP environment. These extensions should now be loaded into your PHP environment, and can be verified using the phpinfo function as described in the PHP installation guide.

And I found lot of possible answers in google

you can go through this links.

1. [Install and Configure MySQL for PHP Applications on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-mysql-for-php-applications-on-iis-7-and-above)
2. [Use the Database Manager](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/database-manager/use-the-database-manager)
3. [Configuring PHP with MySQL for Apache 2 or IIS in Windows](https://www.artfulsoftware.com/php_mysql_win.html)
4. [Install and configure phpMyAdmin on IIS](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/install_and_configure_phpmyadmin_iis)